# Zabbix can't make connection to some zabbix-agents

Tags: connection, zabbix, tcpdump

Currently I'm creating new Zabbix installation (version 6.4.0). Zabbix server is up and running. Everything goes well, but for some host I wish to monitor I can't establish connection to Zabbix server. I've already added some Windows zabbix agents and there is no problem with them, but for some I can't establish connection.

When i do: tcpdump -n tcp dst port 10050 and dst host <here ip address of host I can't connect> there is no output (no packet is sent from zabbix server). But for hosts that work I can see the tcpdump output like this: 07:32:17.008032 IP 192.168.100.201.41034 > 78.21.35.46.zabbix-agent: Flags [P.], seq 436:460, ack 375, win 501, length 24.
What could be the cause of the problem? Any help would be appreciated.
Regards. MJ

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer to myself.
When I was creating new host I had to add template (which I haven't done at first - template field was empty).
Problem was solved.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).